# Why are some tag excerpts cut on the Tags page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-excerpt

Go to the [Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and look at the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag:

[image]

Now look at its excerpt:

[image]

Why is "C# is" cut on the first view?

Comment: Where's the bug?

Comment: Same thing for [tag:python]; I assume someone's been clever and made it so that excerpts starting **`[tag] is`** are truncated so you can fit more of the useful information in.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the tags and their info we can see a pattern if the into starts with

```
[tag] is rest of the tag info
```

Then the tag info on the tag page drops that out and you get

```
 rest of the tag info.
```

If the tag does not start with `[tag] is` then you start from the beginning of the info.  Take [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).  The info is

> JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a dynamic, weakly-typed language typically used for client-side scripting...

And the tag info in the tag screen is:

> JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a dynamic, weakly-typed language typically used for client-side scripting.

But if you look at [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) we have

> C++ is a general-purpose programming language based on C. Use this tag for questions about code compiled with a C++ compiler.

And

> a general-purpose programming language based on C....

Comment: So my question is: is this `status-bydesign`?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani I would say it is based on that it seams to be that way for all tags that follow the formula.  I think a developer would actually have to confirm that.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani it is [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/158100)