# Overzealous stripping of tag excerpt in tag search

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search, tag-excerpt

The tag excerpt for the [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) tag is as follows:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG TO REFER TO THE Stack Overflow website. If you have a question regarding the site, please go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com. A stack overflow occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack.

However, when searching for this tag, the "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" part seems to be stripped.

[image]

Related: [Why are some tag excerpts cut on the Tags page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298210/3853934)

Comment: It looks like the ["avoid repetition" regex](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/1288) must be stripping out everything up to and including "THIS TAG" at the beginning of the tag descriptions.

Comment: It's not likely that the stripping will ever be disabled, so just add this to the endless list of workarounds that had to be made and move on with the workaround edit.